# Incomming references and outgoing references in mssql

Tags: reference

what are incoming references and outgoing references in MSSQL?

Microsoft describes in below link as described below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15

A table can reference a maximum of 253 other tables and columns as foreign keys (outgoing references). SQL Server 2016 (13.x) increases the limit for the number of other tables and columns that can reference columns in a single table (incoming references), from 253 to 10,000.

What does this means?
Do it mean a primary table will have outgoing references and a foreign key table will have incoming references?

Answer (score 0):

Say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
MyTableID INT NOT NULL,
Col1 INT,
Col2 INT,
.
.
.
.
ColN INT,
CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY)
```

`MyTable` can refer to max 253 tables with `Col1` to `ColN` (and `MyTableID`, of course!)

What if other tables want to refer to MyTable?

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
YourTableID INT,
MyTableID INT)

ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_YourTable_MyTable FOREIGN KEY (MyTableID)
REFERENCES MyTable(MyTableID)
```

How many such tables as `YourTable` can refer to `MyTable`'s `MyTableID`?

Though, `MyTable` can refer to as may as 253 tables with its as many as 253 columns, but its `MyTableID` can be referred by as many as 10000 tables!

If the column is referenced by more than 253 tables, update-cascade won't work in all the tables, but delete-cascade will work.